# How to add <int:request-handler-advice-chain /> in Spring Integration FTP Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

In `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter />`, I would like to call external advice,  if the FTP file download is completed or failed (Maybe the advice is run before file download is a nice feature too). How could I do that?

It seems that `<int:request-handler-advice-chain />` could not be added within `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter />`. It seems that advice cold only be added within `<int:poller />` but it means different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request handler advices can only be applied to message handlers; an inbound channel adapter is not a message handler.

See [smart polling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) for how to apply an advice to polled channel adapter.

To get information on a file that is about to be downloaded, you can use a custom `FileListFilter<FTPFile>` to decided whether or not to download the file.

Comment: Thanks. I only use "smart polling" 's beforeReceive before (to check whether the polling of FTP should be proceed or not) and didn't aware that there is a afterReceive() method to fit what I need.